# The best way of creating .CSV files in java

Tags: java, csv

I need to create MAX file for using it in Xerox FreeFlow Process Manager. Most of the data is static, and is just poped out of the mssql database. (And it has nothing to do with Excel.)
What is better in this situation to use? some tools like CSVReader/CSVWriter? Or is it more useful to handle it with the Apache Velocity?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137343/java-csv-parser-comparisons

Answer (score 2):

Use the DB's builtin CSV generator. It's faster and more efficient than you can ever do in Java.

In SQL Server 2005 you can use [SQLCMD](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-2005/how-can-i-export-data-to-csv-format-in-sql-server-2005/) for this:

```
SQLCMD -S MyInstance -E -d sales -i query_file.sql -o output_file.csv -s ,
```